# Flash Update - XML Crash

Tags: xml, flash, updates

My XML has crashed right after a flash update and was wondering if there is a past of Flash updates located somewhere? Including Dates and times and what was updated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for archived Flash Player versions?

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

[image: Archived Flash Player versions]